# May I use "evidence where"?

Tags: grammar

> Modern science has given clear evidence that smoking can lead to many diseases.

in this sentence，“that smoking can lead to many diseases” is an Appositive clause,but I wonder if I can say

> Modern science has given clear evidence where（in which） smoking can lead to many diseases.

what is the difference between them？
please help me，thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you can use *"in which"* or *"where"* here? What research have you done?

Comment: The second one is simply incorrect, whichever form is used. This is not a relative clause (which is the only place you can pied-pipe a preposition to get _in which_). This is a [tensed _that_-complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Complements.pdf), an NP Complement modifying _evidence,_ and saying what it is evidence of. [Relative clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html) and noun complements are both Complex NPs, subject to the [Complex NP Constraint](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html), but they're not at all the same kind of construction.